# jQuery: Hide/Show Divs on page scroll

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/5/

jQuery:

```
function showDiv() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 610) {
        $(".a").css({"position": "fixed", "top": "10px"});
    } else {
        $(".a").css({"position": "relative", "top": "0px"});
    }
}
$(window).scroll(showDiv);
showDiv();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="a">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        B
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so when the user has scrolled past **div "B"** (A and B are out of sight), then **div "A"** will fade in and fix itself to the top of the browser.

When you scroll up and **div "B"** is back in sight, I want **div "A"** to fade out and reposition itself back to where it was originally.

My code currently does just this, EXCEPT it doesn't do fading.

I've tried messing around with `.is(":visible")`, `.is(":hidden")`, `.hide();` so that I can use `fadeIn();` and `fadeOut();`, but no matter what I try, I can't figure it out, and I know this isn't efficient in the first place. There's probably some way to detect if it's passed a div instead of passed a certain coordinate?

Comment: Want to make sure that your Div is closed properly. In your HTML, <div>class="A" is not closed properly.

Comment: I wrote this out within the Stack Overflow form. It's closed within my HTML. Like I said, the code above works, I just can't get it to fade when I want it to.

Comment: **Just an FYI:**  You don't need two lines of code where one will do perfectly; **example:**  `$('.a').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'10px'});`  Also `if ($(window).scrollTop() < 610)` can just be replaced with an `else`

Comment: Thanks for the one liner. As for the `else`, I was just messing around. Here's my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/1/

Comment: You should add your jsFiddle link to your original post.  Here is your same jsFiddle with the [consolidated code as per my last comment](http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/4/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something that should suit your needs:

```
function showDiv() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 610 && $('.a').data('positioned') == 'false') {
        $(".a").hide().css({"position": "fixed", "top": "10px"}).fadeIn().data('positioned', 'true');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 610 && $('.a').data('positioned') == 'true') {
        $(".a").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).css({"position": "relative", "top": "0px"}).show();
        }).data('positioned', 'false');
    }
}
$(window).scroll(showDiv);
$('.a').data('positioned', 'false');
```

And the link to the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/10/

Edit: I have added the code improvements suggested by Sparky672 and the (initially omitted) fadeout.

Comment: This is excellent - almost exactly what I need. I'm trying to decipher it right now, but how can i go about having it fadeOut as well?

Comment: draevor, why not just chain `.data()` as well? Also, the logic is slightly flawed; what about when `scrollTop == 610` ?  See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/9/).  Otherwise +1... barely.

Comment: @Sparky672 Thanks for the suggestions, I've added the improvements and the fadeout. I think the `if`s can be improved as well (not to mention caching the selectors), but I didn't pay that much attention to be honest, just made it work initially :)

Comment: @Aaron I've added the fadeOut and put the new link in place, see the revised post.

Comment: One more suggested tweak... get rid of the confusing `!` and flip the `true/false`.  In other words, instead of `&& !($('.a').data('positioned') == 'true')`, it can just as well be `&& ($('.a').data('positioned') == 'false')`