# How to make a div scroll with the page scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Hide/Show Divs on page scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662751/jquery-hide-show-divs-on-page-scroll)
>   [jQuery - DIV to move with scrolling motion and stick position to top and bottom  of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404172/jquery-div-to-move-with-scrolling-motion-and-stick-position-to-top-and-bottom)

i want my add to scroll up and down with the user scrolls up and down like in [fotbolti.net](http://fotbolti.net)

any help for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404172/jquery-div-to-move-with-scrolling-motion-and-stick-position-to-top-and-bottom **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662751/jquery-hide-show-divs-on-page-scroll

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style="bottom: 0; right: 0px; position: fixed;" >
```

Change your position by top bottom, left right position according your requirement.